# How to restore Eclipse last project tree expand on startup?

Tags: eclipse

When I quit Eclipse some interesting packages are opened. But when I restart Eclipse all projects/packages are collapsed.
Is there a way to save the state of the Project-Explorer on closing Eclipse?

I *don't* want to use the `Link to Editor` feature, because this allways opends packages, that I don't want to expand just for looking up some declaration in an other class.

I also *don't* want to use the `focus view` of `MyLyn`, because I want to be independent of a task and want to see all available packages.

Is there a build in feature of Eclipse to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in a Eclipse-Issue that this feature was removed, because It took to much time in the startup-phase. So this feature does NOT exist in Eclipse without an additional plug-in.

Comment: What plugin would you recommend for this?